# android uiautomator to click ListView

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I have an android app which uses the uiautomator to click the options in a listview. The ListView looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to click the Full Benchmark list item, but my code for it does not recognize the list item. This is what I have:

```
UiScrollable listView = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(
        true).className("android.widget.ListView"));

UiObject item1 = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
.className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()),
        "Full Benchmark");

item1.click();
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I use to find, and then click an item in a listview:

```
//Find and click a ListView item
public void clickListViewItem(String name) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    UiScrollable listView = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector());
    listView.setMaxSearchSwipes(100);
    listView.scrollTextIntoView(name);
    listView.waitForExists(5000);
    UiObject listViewItem = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
            .className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), ""+name+"");
    listViewItem.click();
    System.out.println("\""+name+"\" ListView item was clicked.");
}
```

So in your case it would be

```
clickListViewItem("Full Benchmark")
```

Or:

```
UiScrollable listView = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector());
listView.setMaxSearchSwipes(100);
listView.scrollTextIntoView(name);
listView.waitForExists(5000);
UiObject listViewItem = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
        .className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Full Benchmark");
listViewItem.click();
```

Comment: Is there any way for scrolling and find element in  list based on start text. As this code needs exact name of item. in Many situations as "Language and input" have different text in different devices. How to handle that situation.

Comment: U can get search String from resources with the help of @Rule to support different lang

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches for the above said thing.

**Approach 1:**

1. Analyse UI and then get the instance of the list view say the list view containing text is the 3rd listview
2. Create a Uicollection object like `UiCollection dummyList = new UiCollection(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.ListView").index(3));`
3. Create a object for Benchmark `UiObject dummyBenchmark = dummyList.getChildByText("Full Benchmark");`

**Approach 2:**

```
new UiScrollable(
    new UiSelector().scrollable(true)
).scrollIntoView(
    new UiSelector().text("Full BenchMark")
);
new UiObject(
    new UiSelector().text("Full BenchMark")
).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two TextViews inside a nested ViewGroup most likely LinearLayout. This seems to be missing in the selection criteria.